# Loaded map taking up whole screen in Java GUI application

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jogl, unfoldingmap

I built a Java GUI application which used Unfolding Map included in one of the JPanels.
While the screen was being loaded correctly in my own laptop and in two other laptops, a very strange thing is happening in my professor's laptop.

I had included all the native jogl.jar files as maven dependencies and while the map is being loading correctly, it is taking up the whole screen on loading in my professor's laptop.

Here's a video demonstrating the error:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApQ-BVQCMHxfjBsrt3NTa9owB2g_?e=5DA0ti
OR
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qmxM-2kQcWQXUIfofwVQuNsCb-qwRkKF/view?usp=sharing

This type of error I have never encountered before and I do not know what has caused this. Could someone please help as to what I am missing here?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question and put code and error in the question, as text. I doubt that many people want to watch a video, btw. See also [ask].

Comment: Please modify your source code and use the latest release candidate of JOGL 2.4.0. You use JOGL 1 which is an abandoned and obsolete version of JOGL.

Comment: Ohh thanks all, I will look into the JOGL part